# Replacing receiver on a ceiling fan, but receiver has fewer wires than the fan

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I moved into a place with two fans controlled by one remote, which has been annoying. I bought the [Hampton Bay Universal Thermostatic Ceiling Fan Remote Control](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Universal-Ceiling-Fan-Thermostatic-Remote-68108/205846345) and am trying to replace the existing receiver with the new one. The problem I'm running into is that the ceiling fan has more wires than the new receiver.

**Wiring: Original Fan -> Original Receiver**

- Yellow -> Yellow (labeled "Motor 1")
- White -> White (labeled "Light")
- Red -> Red (labeled "Motor 2")
- Gray -> Gray (labeled "Motor 3")
- Blue -> Blue (not labeled)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB1e9.jpg

**Wiring: New Receiver**

- White (labeled "Motor N")
- Black (labeled "Motor L")
- Blue (labeled "For Light")

How should I safely and correctly wire the new receiver with three wires to the existing ceiling fan with five wires? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post photos of labeling on the original receiver and fan? This may be a case where you'll just plain need a new fan...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel here's a picture of the original receiver labels: https://imgur.com/a/V3betxw

Comment: So I found a replacement receiver for the unit and I might just shell out the $75. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is:

- Motor 1
- Motor 2
- Motor 3

My hunch is that the old fan - and the remote controller - used separate connections for high/medium/slow speed of the fan. The new universal controller uses a single connection (line/neutral) with some sort of controller adjusting the current/voltage/waveform/whatever to appropriately adjust the fan speed. These two methods of control are likely incompatible. There is a small chance that one of the wires (either Motor 1 or Motor 3 - whichever one is "full speed") on the fan could be used with the new remote, but I wouldn't count on it working reliably & efficiently.

Comment: Thanks - I might give that a whirl and see what happens. I was able to track down an actual replacement for the existing remote and receiver so I might just go that route to play it safe. 75 bucks, though :(